# How to convert counts to percentages?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am really new at R and this is probably a really basic question. Please see my sample code. I would like to represent the percentage of people performing weekly work during a 24 hour time period. How can I change the y-axis into percentages instead of totals?

I tried this code but I am not sure of it:

```
df2 <- df3 %>% 
  group_by(day,time) %>% 
  summarise(Total=sum(value)) 
df2$Pct <- df2$Total/ sum(df2$Total)

df2<-structure(list(`Day of the week` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Monday", 
    "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
    ), class = "factor"), time = c(4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 
    5.75, 6, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8, 8.25, 8.5, 8.75, 
    9, 9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 10, 10.25, 10.5, 10.75, 11, 11.25, 11.5, 
    11.75, 12, 12.25, 12.5, 12.75, 13, 13.25, 13.5, 13.75, 14, 14.25, 
    14.5, 14.75, 15, 15.25, 15.5, 15.75, 16, 16.25, 16.5, 16.75, 
    17, 17.25, 17.5, 17.75, 18, 18.25, 18.5, 18.75, 19, 19.25, 19.5, 
    19.75, 20, 20.25, 20.5, 20.75, 21, 21.25, 21.5, 21.75, 22, 22.25, 
    22.5, 22.75, 23, 23.25, 23.5, 23.75, 24, 24.25, 24.5, 24.75, 
    25, 25.25, 25.5, 25.75, 26, 26.25, 26.5, 26.75, 27, 27.25, 27.5, 
    27.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.25, 6.5, 
    6.75, 7, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8, 8.25, 8.5, 8.75, 9, 9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 
    10, 10.25, 10.5, 10.75, 11, 11.25, 11.5, 11.75, 12, 12.25, 12.5, 
    12.75, 13, 13.25, 13.5, 13.75, 14, 14.25, 14.5, 14.75, 15, 15.25, 
    15.5, 15.75, 16, 16.25, 16.5, 16.75, 17, 17.25, 17.5, 17.75, 
    18, 18.25, 18.5, 18.75, 19, 19.25, 19.5, 19.75, 20, 20.25, 20.5, 
    20.75, 21, 21.25, 21.5, 21.75, 22, 22.25, 22.5, 22.75, 23, 23.25, 
    23.5, 23.75, 24, 24.25, 24.5, 24.75, 25, 25.25, 25.5, 25.75, 
    26, 26.25, 26.5, 26.75, 27, 27.25, 27.5, 27.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 
    4.75, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 
    8, 8.25, 8.5, 8.75, 9, 9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 10, 10.25, 10.5, 10.75, 
    11, 11.25, 11.5, 11.75, 12, 12.25, 12.5, 12.75, 13, 13.25, 13.5, 
    13.75, 14, 14.25, 14.5, 14.75, 15, 15.25, 15.5, 15.75, 16, 16.25, 
    16.5, 16.75, 17, 17.25, 17.5, 17.75, 18, 18.25, 18.5, 18.75, 
    19, 19.25, 19.5, 19.75, 20, 20.25, 20.5, 20.75, 21, 21.25, 21.5, 
    21.75, 22, 22.25, 22.5, 22.75, 23, 23.25, 23.5, 23.75, 24, 24.25, 
    24.5, 24.75, 25, 25.25, 25.5, 25.75, 26, 26.25, 26.5, 26.75, 
    27, 27.25, 27.5, 27.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 5.75, 
    6, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8, 8.25, 8.5, 8.75, 9, 
    9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 10, 10.25, 10.5, 10.75, 11, 11.25, 11.5, 11.75, 
    12, 12.25, 12.5, 12.75, 13, 13.25, 13.5, 13.75, 14, 14.25, 14.5, 
    14.75, 15, 15.25, 15.5, 15.75, 16, 16.25, 16.5, 16.75, 17, 17.25, 
    17.5, 17.75, 18, 18.25, 18.5, 18.75, 19, 19.25, 19.5, 19.75, 
    20, 20.25, 20.5, 20.75, 21, 21.25, 21.5, 21.75, 22, 22.25, 22.5, 
    22.75, 23, 23.25, 23.5, 23.75, 24, 24.25, 24.5, 24.75, 25, 25.25, 
    25.5, 25.75, 26, 26.25, 26.5, 26.75, 27, 27.25, 27.5, 27.75, 
    4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7, 
    7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8, 8.25, 8.5, 8.75, 9, 9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 10, 
    10.25, 10.5, 10.75, 11, 11.25, 11.5, 11.75, 12, 12.25, 12.5, 
    12.75, 13, 13.25, 13.5, 13.75, 14, 14.25, 14.5, 14.75, 15, 15.25, 
    15.5, 15.75, 16, 16.25, 16.5, 16.75, 17, 17.25, 17.5, 17.75, 
    18, 18.25, 18.5, 18.75, 19, 19.25, 19.5, 19.75, 20, 20.25, 20.5, 
    20.75, 21, 21.25, 21.5, 21.75, 22, 22.25, 22.5, 22.75, 23, 23.25, 
    23.5, 23.75, 24, 24.25, 24.5, 24.75, 25, 25.25, 25.5, 25.75, 
    26, 26.25, 26.5, 26.75, 27, 27.25, 27.5, 27.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 
    4.75, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 
    8, 8.25, 8.5, 8.75, 9, 9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 10, 10.25, 10.5, 10.75, 
    11, 11.25, 11.5, 11.75, 12, 12.25, 12.5, 12.75, 13, 13.25, 13.5, 
    13.75, 14, 14.25, 14.5, 14.75, 15, 15.25, 15.5, 15.75, 16, 16.25, 
    16.5, 16.75, 17, 17.25, 17.5, 17.75, 18, 18.25, 18.5, 18.75, 
    19, 19.25, 19.5, 19.75, 20, 20.25, 20.5, 20.75, 21, 21.25, 21.5, 
    21.75, 22, 22.25, 22.5, 22.75, 23, 23.25, 23.5, 23.75, 24, 24.25, 
    24.5, 24.75, 25, 25.25, 25.5, 25.75, 26, 26.25, 26.5, 26.75, 
    27, 27.25, 27.5, 27.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 5.75, 
    6, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8, 8.25, 8.5, 8.75, 9, 
    9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 10, 10.25, 10.5, 10.75, 11, 11.25, 11.5, 11.75, 
    12, 12.25, 12.5, 12.75, 13, 13.25, 13.5, 13.75, 14, 14.25, 14.5, 
    14.75, 15, 15.25, 15.5, 15.75, 16, 16.25, 16.5, 16.75, 17, 17.25, 
    17.5, 17.75, 18, 18.25, 18.5, 18.75, 19, 19.25, 19.5, 19.75, 
    20, 20.25, 20.5, 20.75, 21, 21.25, 21.5, 21.75, 22, 22.25, 22.5, 
    22.75, 23, 23.25, 23.5, 23.75, 24, 24.25, 24.5, 24.75, 25, 25.25, 
    25.5, 25.75, 26, 26.25, 26.5, 26.75, 27, 27.25, 27.5, 27.75), 
        Total = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 19, 22, 27, 28, 44, 47, 
        56, 59, 100, 106, 135, 136, 173, 184, 191, 197, 200, 199, 
        203, 201, 198, 199, 202, 202, 193, 189, 182, 183, 155, 153, 
        153, 157, 183, 185, 185, 185, 185, 182, 173, 172, 158, 158, 
        140, 139, 125, 118, 108, 101, 68, 66, 54, 50, 37, 38, 32, 
        30, 26, 26, 26, 25, 24, 23, 23, 23, 25, 23, 21, 20, 15, 14, 
        14, 15, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 14, 15, 20, 20, 27, 27, 45, 
        47, 59, 62, 104, 110, 137, 140, 179, 186, 202, 203, 206, 
        209, 209, 210, 205, 207, 211, 210, 200, 199, 194, 197, 169, 
        166, 176, 180, 193, 196, 197, 197, 192, 190, 180, 176, 162, 
        162, 153, 148, 124, 122, 106, 97, 64, 61, 57, 54, 38, 37, 
        38, 34, 32, 33, 31, 28, 24, 24, 22, 21, 20, 20, 17, 16, 13, 
        12, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 
        8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 11, 14, 16, 22, 24, 27, 28, 45, 48, 63, 
        66, 104, 116, 141, 145, 191, 198, 209, 210, 215, 216, 218, 
        216, 216, 218, 221, 221, 206, 204, 194, 194, 180, 179, 184, 
        186, 206, 209, 208, 207, 204, 203, 196, 194, 179, 182, 168, 
        164, 131, 127, 115, 106, 66, 60, 57, 52, 39, 36, 36, 33, 
        32, 31, 29, 29, 22, 21, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 14, 12, 12, 12, 
        11, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
        5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 18, 20, 21, 21, 38, 39, 58, 61, 108, 116, 
        138, 141, 179, 185, 196, 196, 200, 205, 205, 201, 202, 204, 
        204, 202, 191, 188, 184, 188, 170, 172, 180, 178, 190, 191, 
        196, 195, 193, 194, 184, 180, 165, 166, 150, 149, 128, 123, 
        108, 99, 66, 66, 60, 55, 36, 36, 33, 34, 35, 35, 31, 31, 
        22, 22, 22, 22, 17, 17, 15, 14, 12, 12, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        10, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 
        12, 12, 21, 21, 25, 27, 43, 44, 56, 59, 100, 110, 129, 132, 
        166, 172, 187, 189, 189, 191, 193, 192, 188, 194, 193, 192, 
        173, 173, 172, 176, 159, 154, 157, 163, 166, 167, 170, 169, 
        162, 161, 157, 156, 141, 142, 130, 125, 92, 91, 73, 68, 46, 
        47, 40, 35, 24, 23, 21, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 19, 19, 17, 17, 
        20, 19, 18, 18, 11, 11, 12, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 7, 7, 
        7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 9, 11, 12, 13, 
        14, 14, 15, 20, 20, 20, 21, 26, 26, 28, 29, 32, 33, 40, 40, 
        38, 37, 43, 43, 44, 43, 43, 44, 43, 41, 40, 39, 39, 40, 39, 
        38, 37, 37, 39, 41, 33, 34, 37, 36, 34, 34, 35, 33, 28, 28, 
        24, 24, 19, 19, 19, 18, 18, 19, 17, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 14, 
        14, 15, 15, 14, 13, 13, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4, 
        4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 
        7, 8, 8, 9, 14, 14, 15, 16, 18, 18, 17, 16, 18, 18, 20, 20, 
        21, 22, 25, 25, 30, 30, 29, 28, 25, 24, 23, 23, 22, 21, 21, 
        21, 20, 21, 23, 23, 23, 22, 21, 23, 19, 18, 19, 18, 19, 19, 
        21, 21, 16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 15, 
        15, 17, 17, 18, 17, 16, 16, 13, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 10, 
        9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -672L
    ), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
        day = structure(1:7, .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
        .rows = list(1:96, 97:192, 193:288, 289:384, 385:480, 481:576, 
            577:672)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: If a person works multiple 15 minute increments in a day, is that person counted in each quarter hour? If so, summing across a day makes the denominator the number of 15 minute increments worked in a day. If you want the percentage of `people` rather than time increments, you would use the maximum value of `Total` across the 7 day period. Please describe how the denominator in the percentage should be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart in the other answer illustrates the percentage of people working in each 15 minute increment by day, given the total number of 15 minute increments worked during a day.

If the y axis is to represent the percentage of people working in any 15 minute increment during the week, the denominator should be `max(Total)`, the maximum number of people working in any 15 minute increment across the 7 day time period in the data.

Another approach would be to use the maximum value by day, so during the 15 minute increment were the most people worked that day would render in the chart as 100%.

By summarizing the data we can see how the denominators would be calculated.

```
df2 %>% 
    group_by(`Day of the week`) %>% 
    summarise(.,max = max(Total))
```

...and the output:

```
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  `Day of the week`   max
  <fct>             <dbl>
1 Monday              203
2 Tuesday             211
3 Wednesday           221
4 Thursday            205
5 Friday              194
6 Saturday             44
7 Sunday               30
```

A chart normalized to the maximum number of workers per day looks like this, given the chart that was posted in the original answer:

```
df2 %>% group_by(`Day of the week`) %>%
     mutate(Percent = Total / max(Total)) -> df3

ggplot(df3,aes(x=time,y=Percent,color=`Day of the week`))+
     geom_line() +
     scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

...and the output:

[image]

A chart normalized to the maximum number of workers across all days looks like this.

```
df2  %>% ungroup() %>%
     mutate(Percent = Total / max(Total)) -> df3

ggplot(df3,aes(x=time,y=Percent,color=`Day of the week`))+
     geom_line() +
     scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

...and the output, where we can clearly see that fewer people were working on weekends.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest next approach. If you group by day and time all percentages are 1. If grouping by day you get this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Compute
f2 %>% group_by(`Day of the week`) %>% mutate(Percentage=Total/sum(Total)) -> f3
#Plot
ggplot(f3,aes(x=time,y=Percentage,color=`Day of the week`))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Output:

[image]